# Ensuring endianness in c++ streams

Tags: c++, stream, endianness

Is there a built-in way to ensure the endianness of multi-byte types in C++ streams? In particular, I want to use `read()` and `write()` to read/write small char arrays to/from a stream. I need to ensure that these will always be stored in little-endian format. (Yes, I could do it one byte at a time or with shifting & etc., but that's not my question.)

Comment: You mean the inbound data or the outbound?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense to me, but I mean that the data in the streambuf should be in little-endian format.

Comment: endianess on 1 byte object is not relevant. This only applies to objects of more than 1 byte. The stream will never re-arrange the elementsso what you put in is what you get out **in the same order**.

Comment: @LokiAstari That was the source of my confusion: whether streams treat an array as a multi-byte object or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For char arrays you don't need to worry about endianness since each character is a single byte. If you are coding things like integers as a series of bytes, then your stream needs to read and write not as a char array, but as a typed array so you know what you are dealing with. That is, by the time you have cast your integers into bytes you've lost the information necessary to recover endianness.

Comment: So if I have a char string `s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}` and I do a `write(s, 3)`, then in memory I'll have 'a' at the lowest address and 'b' at the highest? Also, I'm not encoding integers or anything, I need the specific bytes ordered for custom socket headers and such.

Comment: Yes. Endianness usually refer to byte order of multi-byte types. Characters are single bytes, so they get written in the same order on all modern platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee that. I'm pretty sure that is determined by the architecture anyway, rather than the compiler. There are ways to check the endianness, though.

In your particular case, there is not really a worry because as far as I know, every serious implementation of C++ stores `char`s as a single byte.

Comment: A `char` is **by definition** a single byte, i.e. `sizeof(char)==1`, see §5.3.3/1.  A byte is not required to be 8 bits, it could be more, see §1.7/1.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way to do this without shifts - the architecture will force you to have them in a certain order in memory when you're working with it - the easiest workaround is to use a byte-order-mark.  If this is unacceptable, I'm afraid you have to use shifts.

And to check that your assumptions are correct, you can say something like

```
static_assert(sizeof(char) == 1, "Chars are not one byte!!!!????");
```

Answer (score 0):

For chars arrays, "what the other people said".

For more complex data types, instead of rolling your own, take a look at existing serialization projects. At the time of this writing, google's protobuf doesn't seem like a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

this function can check the endianness of your system simply:

```
void print_endianness() {
    union {
        unsigned int i;
        char c[4];
    } un;
    un.i = 0x12345678;

    if (un.c[0] == 0x78 && un.c[3] == 0x12)
        printf("little-endian\n");
    else if (un.c[0] == 0x12 && un.c[3] == 0x78)
        printf("big-endian\n");
    else
        printf("unknown\n");
}
```